# Angular2 stable version has no named-routerOutlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
<router-outlet name="some_name"></router-outlet>
& the routes goes as {path: '', component: SomeComponent}
```

TS doesn't recognize it.

```
'name' doesn't exists in route
```

How to achieve it in the new version..!

Comment: Here is the updated documention, on how to use routes: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: So in new doc, its not available.. but I am not able to findout how to call multiple router-outlets in single page.

Comment: You could nest them in the component tree, is that en option in your setup?

Comment: which means never use <router-outlet> .. ?

Comment: have you tried using `{path: '', component: SomeComponent, outlets:'some_name'}`?

Comment: yes.. string: 'outlets' doesn't exist in type route.

Comment: Oops my mistake. its `outlet` only.

Comment: I have tried with this.. { path: '', component: AppComponent, outlet: 'some_name'}, now I get-  Error: Cannot match any routes: ''.

Comment: Just min I'm writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to use **named-router-outlet**

```
eg. <router-outlet name="some_name"></router-outlet>
```

For that you can use new property called `outlet` with routing as shown below,

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: '', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'details'}  //<<<===Check here
```

This route says, Whenever I run my application, I want to inject **HomeView** in **normal router-outlet** but inject **DetailView** in **named-router-outlet**. Use all together in component like,

```
@Component({
  selector:"my-app",
  template:`
    <h3>Normal router-outlet</h3>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <hr>

    <h3> Router-outlet with name attribute</h3>
       <router-outlet name='details'></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent{
}
```

**Working Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/5Cv8TewVDPNtpn56f6gS?p=preview**

Comment: it doesn't cover up the whole answer.. now if we include {path:"some_path", component:Details}.. then Error: Cannot match any routes: 'some_path' in Route ...!

Comment: Show me in plunker. Show me your problem.

Comment: BTW look at your question, it doesn't reveal such information. This answer is given with respect to your question only.

Comment: I am sorry @micronyks, I mean the problem still persists in same context, and please help me out to sort this. https://plnkr.co/edit/Un3XNFk0ZundelOgqg15?p=catalogue

I am new to plunker, so everything within index.html juz the change we have..

Comment: What do u want to do? tell me. i m not getting what you want.

Comment: Lets take the same example that you have given, in that instead of {path: '', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'details'}, if we have {path: 'details', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'details'}, and include a <a>click to show Details</a> in app.component. Then on click of Link the DetatilsTemplate wont be displayed. Error finding"details" in routes.
So I need to achieve that on click get me the template..

Comment: This can be a bug or something beyond my knowledge. We need to confirm from Angular2 Community.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124060/discussion-between-micronyks-and-peaceuser).